# NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: +(" ")

Tags: flutter

I'm fetching data from the server, with success. But in my app, I want one-time login, in my case when I log in to my app then I can logged in successfully but when I clear my app from memory and then open it again then first it shows splash screen after that it will show this error: `"No Such Method Error: The method '+' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: +(" ")."` I tried so many solutions from stack overflow but I can't get exact solution.

Login

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:bar_app/Home.dart';
import 'package:bar_app/Methods/ALLResourceMethods.dart';
import 'package:bar_app/Models/ALLModels.dart';
import 'package:bar_app/SignUp1.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Login());
}

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<Login> {

  TextEditingController getEmail = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController getPassword = TextEditingController();

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    exit(0);
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image(
                            image: new AssetImage("images/logoorg.png"),
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Welcome back.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 62),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
                            height: 50,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 4, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 4),
                            decoration:
                                BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                            ]),
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: getEmail,
                              autofocus: true,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Email'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
                            height: 50,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 4, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 4),
                            decoration:
                                BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                            ]),
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: getPassword,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Password'),
                              obscureText: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'Login',
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                              ),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                 Login1.SignIn(getEmail.toString(),getPassword.toString(), context);
                                });
                              },
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 8.0,
                                  vertical: 5.0), // gives padding to the button
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                              child: new GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => SignUp1()),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: new Text(
                                  "SIGN UP",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

API Calling  method here I set shared preference data

class Login1 {
  static Future<LoginModel> SignIn(
      String email, String password, context) async {
    var url = 'https://bruyou.project-demo.info/api/V1/customer/login';
    Map data = {
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    };
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    if (responseJson["status"] == "error") {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    } else {
      var dataModel = LoginModel.fromJson(responseJson);
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString("id", dataModel.successData.id.toString());
      prefs.setString("token", dataModel.successData.rememberToken);
      prefs.setString("fn", dataModel.successData.firstName);
      prefs.setString("ln", dataModel.successData.lastName);
      prefs.setString("img", dataModel.successData.profileImage);
      prefs.setString("pn", dataModel.successData.phoneNumber);
      prefs.setString("isTrue", "true");
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Home(
            pn: dataModel.successData.phoneNumber,
            img: dataModel.successData.profileImage,
            fn: dataModel.successData.firstName,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

Splash screen code

import 'package:bar_app/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'Login.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext contextP) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: splash());
  }
}

class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<splash> {
  var CheckToken = null;
  var Check = null;

  oneTime() async{
    SharedPreferences Preference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var Check = Preference.getString("isTrue");
    var fn= Preference.getString("fn");
    //var ln= Preference.getString("ln");
    var img= Preference.getString("img");
    var pn= Preference.getString("pn");
    print("fnnnn"+fn);
    if (Check == "true") {
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 5),
        () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home(fn: fn,img: img,pn:pn)),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 5),
        () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    oneTime();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Image(
                  image: new AssetImage("images/photofunky.gif"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet, so, it will be easy to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in this line

```
 print("fnnnn"+fn);
```

fn is null so it calls the concationation on a null which dosent support string concatination

Comment: i did this i remove print statement but same error occur

Comment: well it seems your appliying the + operator on a nullish value which throws the error